# GRUB issue: trying to add android x86 and does not appear

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub, android

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu. Have a laptop acer  aspire ES15. Windows 10 is pre-installed. I have after much trouble managed to get grub to run with Ubuntu and Windows options appearing. Have created a new partition for Android X86 release 6 installed on sda8. Followed steps for custom 40 file changes. Problem is when I run grub-update I get this error message.

```
root@nazir-Aspire-ES1-531:~# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
error: out of memory.
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 391
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
done
```

Here is the grub.cfg.new file

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_ZA
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-42-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-42-generic-advanced-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-42-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-42-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-42-generic-init-upstart-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-42-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-42-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-42-generic-recovery-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-42-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-36-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-36-generic-advanced-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-36-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-36-generic-init-upstart-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-36-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-36-generic-recovery-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-31-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-31-generic-advanced-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-31-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-31-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-31-generic-init-upstart-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-31-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-31-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-31-generic-recovery-140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-31-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=140a7c82-bbfe-4c8a-ac47-9bde586a023b ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

menuentry "Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root F205-5795
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root F205-5795
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}

menuentry "EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root F205-5795
chainloader (${root})/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
}

menuentry "EFI/OEM/Boot/bootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root F205-5795
chainloader (${root})/EFI/OEM/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/25_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-F205-5795' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  F205-5795
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F205-5795
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Android-x86" {
set root='(hd0,8)'
linux /android-6.0-r1/kernel
initrd /android-6.0-r1/initrd.img
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

The last line above is 391.

Please advise what to do

Answer (score -1):

Well for one thing, Android isn't for PCs. The closest thing to Android for a PC is Chrome OS. If you want Android on your laptop, I highly advise using the free SDK as it has a virtual machine program for Android releases. It could also be because GRUB is running out of RAM to process your OSes as hinted here:
`error: out of memory.`. How much RAM do you have on your laptop?

Comment: Thanks for the input.
There is 2GB of RAM on the system. 
It is strange. When I installed it and before reboot it ran super fast and did not bring up any issues. Just on reboot it did not appear on the GRUB. Thus my attempt to get it added to the menu.  The one suspicion I have is that there is an error with the entry before the android code and it does get to it. 
How do I move up the android command lines to appear before the windows one. 
Best wishes

Comment: @NazirIsmail If you press and hold the shift key in GRUB it will bring up it's options however I'm not sure if that will work if it errors out like that. You also might want to get a bigger RAM chip, 2 GB isn't that big, but that SHOULD be enough to load your operating systems.